# Where do I set the focus on the input element in the modal prompt example?

Tags: javascript

Where do I set the focus on the input element in the modal prompt example?

https://codepen.io/bravotanmoy/pen/xXoody

I tried at the end of this.render = ... and after it without success

```
document.getElementById("prompt_value1").focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the **end of the render function**:

```
document.querySelector('#dialogbox input').focus();
```

You can test it in [this pen](https://codepen.io/amirhshahbazi-the-flexboxer/pen/YzVRLWK).

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the focus is not set.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: The latest chrome. It now works when I call document.getElementById("prompt_value1").focus()

Comment: I've edited the post and added a working pen if you haven't fixed the problem yet.